# Change XmlElement name for XML serialisation

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

We have the followig code:

```
[Serializable]
public class Class1
{
    [XmlElement("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Class1> {new Class1() {Description = "Desc1"}, new Class1() {Description = "Desc2"}};
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Class1>), new XmlRootAttribute("root"));
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.Serialize(ms, list);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var result = new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

after execution we will have the following in 'result' variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Class1>
    <description>Desc1</description>
  </Class1>
  <Class1>
    <description>Desc2</description>
  </Class1>
</root>
```

The question is: how to change xml elements name from 'Class1' to 'Item1' without changing class name?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use [`XmlTypeAttribute.TypeName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.typename.aspx) for this.

Try this for you `Class1` definition

```
    [XmlType(TypeName = "Item1")]
    [Serializable]
    public class Class1
    {
        [XmlElement("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Any way to have a dynamic name generation dependent on the property name? (ie: instead of having [XmlElement("description")] to have some dynamic code that does, say CurrentName.ToLowerCase() ) and Description will be description?

Answer (score 6):

Use an [`XmlTypeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.aspx) on the class as well:

```
[XmlType(TypeName="ElementName")]
[Serializable]
public class Class1 { ...
```

**EDIT**: Updated from `XmlRootAttribute` to `XmlTypeAttribute`. The former works where the type being passed to the serialiser is the attributed type (`Class1` here), but not when there is a wrapping type (`List<Class1>` here). That `XmlType` works is not clear from the documentation (my emphasis):

> Controls the XML *schema* that is generated when the attribute target is serialized by the XmlSerializer.

Credit to Bala R's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385208/change-xmlelement-name-for-xml-serialisation/6386271#6386271).

Comment: I don't think XmlElementAttribute can be applied for classes.`[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Property|AttributeTargets.Field|AttributeTargets.Parameter|AttributeTargets.ReturnValue, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class XmlElementAttribute : Attribute` and there is no `AttributeTargets.Class`

Comment: The System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute has AttributeUsage:
Field | Parameter | Property | ReturnValue but not the Type

Comment: @TheOtherGuy... it should, look at the sample on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx)... but that `List<Class1>` is messing things up.

Comment: Any way to have a dynamic name generation dependent on the property name? (ie: instead of having [XmlElement("description")] to have some dynamic code that does, say CurrentName.ToLowerCase() ) and Description will be description?