# How to serialize a custom object with a list of another custom object in a particular schema when this list of custom objects is a generic type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, generics, serialization

I need to create a lot of XML files. They are very similar and they need to have the following schema:

```
<Servidor>
  <VersaoLayout>0001</VersaoLayout> <!--Will not change-->
  <CodigoUJ>001001</CodigoUJ>       <!--Will not change-->
    <ItemServidor>                  <!--A list of <T> that will change-->
      <CPFServidor>13579024681</CPFServidor>
      <NomeServidor>Fulano Pereira Tal</NomeServidor>
    </ItemServidor>
</Servidor>
```

Note that the tags `<VersaoLayout>` and `<CodigoUJ>` are the same for all the files i need to create, the `<ItemServidor>` is the content that will vary. So i thought: Why not create just one class and use  generics to handle the differences for this case? And for now my classes are the following:

```
//Kind of a container class that will hold the content that will vary.
[XmlRoot("Servidor", ElementName="Servidor")]
public class LayoutArquivoXML<T> where T : ItemLayout
{
    [XmlElement("VersaoLayout")]
    public string VersaoLayout { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CodigoUJ")]
    public string CodigoUJ { get; set; }

    //[XmlArrayItem("ItemServidor")]
    public List<T> ItensLayout { get; set; }

    // Constructors omited for simplicity
}

//A "ContentClass". I will have a bunch of classes similar to this
[XmlRoot("ItemServidor", ElementName = "ItemServidor")]
public class ServidorLayout : ItemLayout  
{
    [XmlElement("CPFServidor")]
    public string CPFServidor { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("NomeServidor")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

I am instantiating my "container class" this way:

```
LayoutArquivoXML<ServidorLayout> layout = new Layout.LayoutArquivoXML<ServidorLayout>("versao01", "999", lstItensLayout.ToList());
```

And my Serialization method is the following:

```
 public string Serializador<T>(T objeto)
 {
     string xml = string.Empty;
     using (var sw = new ISO8859StringWriter())
     {
         XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
         ns.Add("", ""); // to omit XML namespaces
         var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
         xs.Serialize(sw, objeto, ns);
      }
      return xml;
  }
```

These objects graph are generating a XML with the following schema:

```
<Servidor>
  <VersaoLayout>versao01</VersaoLayout>
  <CodigoUJ>999</CodigoUJ>
  <ItensLayout>
    <ServidorLayout>
      <CPFServidor>4252813450</CPFServidor>
      <NomeServidor>Antonio de Sousa Muniz</NomeServidor>
    </ServidorLayout>
  </ItensLayout>
</Serv>
```

I dont want the tag `<ItensLayout>` tag in the XML. What i need to do to generate the XML in the desired schema?

Also, the root tag `<Servidor>` will need to change according to the file i am generating, imagine that i need to create another file where the root tag is **Another**, let say:

```
LayoutArquivoXML<AnotherLayout> layout = new Layout.LayoutArquivoXML<AnotherLayout>("versao01", "999", anotherItensLayout.ToList());
```

Comment: You are asking independent questions.  Your first question, how to make the element name match the generic parameter type name, is very similar to [C#: Best way to have XML element name from generic type name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38344516/3744182).  For your second question, about how to modify the root name of a generic, you will need to subclass `LayoutArquivoXML<AnotherLayout>` or use `XmlRootAttribute` as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23897411/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate issues.

> I don't want the tag `<ItensLayout>` tag in the XML. What i need to do to generate the XML in the desired schema?

As explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/framework/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes) for **Serializing an Array as a Sequence of Elements**, to serialize an array (list, enumerable etc.) as flat sequence of XML elements, you need to apply `XmlElement` attribute to the property/field.

> Also, the root tag `<Servidor>` will need to change according to the file i am generating

This is controlled by the `XmlRoot` attribute.

Now, all this applies if you are using concrete classes. In order to apply them dynamically to your generic class, you can use the [`XmlOverrides`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides?view=netframework-4.7) class and the `XmlSerializer` [constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.7) accepting such parameter.

To do that, first add an optional parameter to your original method:

```
public string Serializador<T>(T objeto, XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = null)
{
    string xml = string.Empty;
    using (var sw = new ISO8859StringWriter())
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", ""); // to omit XML namespaces
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), overrides);
        xs.Serialize(sw, objeto, ns);
        xml = sw.ToString();
    }
    return xml;
}
```

Then create a specific method like this:

```
public string Serializador<T>(LayoutArquivoXML<T> objeto, string rootElementName, string contentElementName)
     where T : ItemLayout
{
    var xmlAttrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    // Root element name override
    var xmlRootAttrs = new XmlAttributes();
    xmlRootAttrs.XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute(rootElementName);
    xmlAttrOverrides.Add(typeof(LayoutArquivoXML<T>), xmlRootAttrs);
    // Content element name override
    var xmlContentAttrs = new XmlAttributes();
    xmlContentAttrs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute(contentElementName));
    xmlAttrOverrides.Add(typeof(LayoutArquivoXML<T>), "ItensLayout", xmlContentAttrs);
    // Call the original method passing the overrides
    return Serializador(objeto, xmlAttrOverrides);
}
```

Now you can achieve your goal by using something like this:

```
var source = new LayoutArquivoXML<ServidorLayout>
{
    VersaoLayout = "0001",
    CodigoUJ = "001001",
    ItensLayout = new List<ServidorLayout>
    {
        new ServidorLayout
        {
            CPFServidor = "13579024681",
            Nome = "Fulano Pereira Tal",
        },
    }
};

var xml = Serializador(source, "Servidor", "ItemServidor");
```

which produces:

```
<Servidor>
  <VersaoLayout>0001</VersaoLayout>
  <CodigoUJ>001001</CodigoUJ>
  <ItemServidor>
    <CPFServidor>13579024681</CPFServidor>
    <NomeServidor>Fulano Pereira Tal</NomeServidor>
  </ItemServidor>
</Servidor>
```

Comment: Thanks, its perfect!